# Run Ansible handlers based on changed results in multiple loops

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible variable containing a list of web servers (all on the same host):

```
servers:
  - foo
  - bar
  - baz
```

And a task that changes their config files, and registers the results in a variable:

```
- name: create server configs
  template: ...
  with_items: "{{ servers }}"
  notify: restart changed servers
  register: servers_changed
```

And a handler that restarts only the servers that are changed when that task runs:

```
- name: restart changed servers
  command: restart-my-server {{ item.item.name }}
  when: item.changed
  with_items: "{{ servers_changed.results }}"
```

My problem is, I now need multiple tasks like the one above, which change different config files. But if I do that, they'll overwrite the `servers_changed` variable, so only the last one will be used.

I could register different variables in each tasks, but then I need a different handler for each one. This would get messy. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found an approach that I prefer. This creates a variable `restart_servers`, containing an array of server names that need to be restarted. After updating a config file, add the changed items to the variable.

vars:

```
servers:
- name: server1
  port: 1000
- name: server2
  port: 1001
```

tasks:

```
- name: create server configs
  template: ...
  with_items: "{{ servers }}"
  notify: restart changed servers
  register: servers_changed

- name: remember which servers need to restart
  set_fact:
    restart_servers: "{{ restart_servers | default([]) + [item.item.name] }}"
  when: item.changed
  with_items: "{{ servers_changed.results }}"
```

handlers:

```
- name: restart changed servers
  command: restart-my-server {{ item.name }}
  when: item.name in restart_servers | default([])
  with_items: "{{ servers }}"
```

The disadvantage is that after each task that might trigger a restart, you need a second task to call set_fact based on the servers that changed.

The advantage is that it's easy to understand, and avoids duplicate handlers or duplicate restarts.

Comment: Cool. But why not to use `with_items: "{{restart_servers}}"` directly in the handler, eliminating this `when` ...?

Comment: @WojciechKaczmarek I guess I simplified things a little too much for my example. In my real setup, `servers` is a list of dicts, with details about each server, but `restart_servers` is just a list of names identifying each server. You could have the handler loop over `restart_servers` instead, but looping over `servers` lets it access the details about each server it's restarting. As an example, I have my handler look at each server's port number, and wait for it to become open before continuing.

Comment: Yeah I was suspecting that you dragged this code from some bigger, real-life context. 
Thanks for updating the example.

Answer (score 5):

Use `servers_changed` as a composite list and concatenate the results of each task:

```
- name: create server configs
  template: ...
  with_items: "{{ servers }}"
  notify: restart changed servers
  register: servers_changed_now

- set_fact:
    servers_changed: "{{ servers_changed | default([]) | union(servers_changed_now.results|default([]) }}"
```

and

```
- name: restart changed servers
  command: restart-my-server {{ item.item.name }}
  when: item.changed
  with_items: "{{ servers_changed }}"
```

Comment: I ended up writing a custom filter to use in set_fact, which merges the registered variables, but ignores duplicate servers (to avoid restarting a server more than once).

Comment: Actually there's no need for custom filters here, I updated the answer to handle empty lists and duplicate entries.

Comment: I don't think that will eliminate duplicate servers, since you have to look in item.item to find the server name.

Comment: This would eliminate duplicate items. Depending on how exactly you prepare your templates it might, or might not. You know better what's inside.